# R codes with time series

Tags: r, time-series, logarithm

I am starting to use R and I have found out this code below, the only part of the code I haven't understood is `log(ts(GDPUS[-1, 3]))`, I don't understand the purpose of `[-1, 3]`. Can someone explain it to me?

---

```
 GDPUS=read_excel("TS1year_csv.xlsx")

 years=seq(1930, 2015, by = 1)

 levelGDPUS=log(ts(GDPUS[-1, 3]))

 plot(years, levelGDPUS, xlab="Year", ylab="Logarithm", typ=’l’, col="blue", axes=FALSE) 

 axis(2,at=seq(4.0, 10.0, by=0.5)); axis(1, at=seq(1930,2010,by=10)); box()
```

Comment: can you include the first few rows of TS1year_csv.xlsx in your code so that this is reproducible?

Answer (score 1):

The number before the `,` stands for the row. The `-1` in `GDPUS[-1, 3]` means that you exclude the first row of your data frame, because of the `-`. The number after the `,` stands for the column. Hence `3` stands for  third column in the data frame.

So your variable `levelGDPUS` is the `log` of the third column minus the first row of the data frame.

Let me know if this awnsered your question.